# htaccess mod_rewrite regular expressions

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have an old website that are indexed very well on Google and then I need to make 301's to let ex. Google know that the page is moved.

I moved my site from Wordpress to a "builded OS", but with single urls.

It goes very well with the first page, but when I need to 301 redirect the sub links it fails.

Code:

```
Redirect 301 /what-we-do/ mypage.nu/services
Redirect 301 /what-we-do/about-us mypage.nu/about
```

Second line fucks and makes it "servicesabout" - which cant be found.

How can I make hyphen (-) from old url and sub url, to direct to "single urls" - with this I mean from ex. mypage.nu/what-we-do/about-us/members to ex mypage.nu/members

Please help me, I'd tried several regulair expressions ex

```
Redirect 301 /what-we-do/about([^/_]+?)-?us mypage.nu/about
```

Nothing works, but I can fine do a RewriteMatch - so the mod_rewrite is activated on my server.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Use `RedirectMatch` for regex support to match exact URLs:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/what-we-do/?$ mypage.nu/services
RedirectMatch 301 ^/what-we-do/about-us/?$ mypage.nu/about
```

Better to test this in a new browser to avoid old cache.